# how to display uploaded file size in need for minimal file upload django example

Tags: html, django

i needed to display file size in my html code along with changes in views and models.please help me to do this.

views.py
this is my view code.changes to display file size when it is uploaded

```
 def index(request):

    response = TemplateResponse(request, 'login.html', {})
    return response

 def login(request, username, password):
    user = username[:-1]


    for i in AppUser.objects.all():
        if ( user == i.username and password == i.password ):
            return list(request)
        else:
             return index(request)

  def list(request):
   # Handle file upload
         print "im getting in"

         if request.method == 'POST':
           form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
           if form.is_valid():
              newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'],created_at = datetime.datetime.now())
              newdoc.save()

        # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return   HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cloudStorageManager.views.list'))

          else:
             print "else"
            form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

            # Load documents for the list page
            documents = Document.objects.all()

           # Render list page with the documents and the form
              return render_to_response('list.html',{'documents': documents, 'form': form, 'created_at': datetime.datetime.now()},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py
attribute for displaying file size

```
  class Document(models.Model):
     docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
     created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True , blank=True)
```

list.html
html code to display the file size while uploading

```
        {% for document in documents %}
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="case" id="chk{{forloop.counter}}" value="{{ document.docfile.name }}">
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ document.docfile.name }}  {{ document.created_at }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}"   target="_blank" title="Download"><button class="btn btn-success btn-flat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download">          </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Download</button></a></td>
                    <td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ document.docfile.size |filesizeformat}}
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.size) for File size. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#filesizeformat) for filesizeformat filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can know the size and validate the uploaded files in your forms.py file.

```
class DOcumentForm(...):
    ...
    docfile = forms.FileField(...)
    ...

    def clean_docfile(self):
        current_size = self.cleaned_data['docfile'].size
        if current_size < 2621440 # size in bytes:
            return self.cleaned_data['docfile']
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Max 2.5 MB allowed. Current size is {0}'.format(current_size))
```

Comment: The above code is for *maximum allowed* file size. If you want *minimum required*, just reverse the `<` (equality) sign. Also the error message.